# Use hyphen in impala database name

Tags: hadoop, impala

I have a script which directly requires the creation of impala databases using hyphen in the database name.

I am not able to do the same in impala shell using the below command.

```
******** default> create database test-1;
Query: create database test-1
ERROR: AnalysisException: Invalid database name: test-1
```

Even back tick does not help

```
******** default> create database `test-1`;
Query: create database `test-1`
ERROR: AnalysisException: Invalid database name: test-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, according to [Impala documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_identifiers.html) from Cloudera it doesn't sound possible:

> o  An identifier must start with an alphanumeric or underscore character.
>   The remainder can contain any combination of alphanumeric characters
>   and underscores. **Quoting the identifier with backticks has no effect
>   on the allowed characters in the name.**